# What should I use to pass data to other component. React Hooks or Context API or Redux or prop drilling. Which one will be better for performance

Tags: reactjs

I can pass data to other **REACT** component using **React Hooks**, **Context API** and **Prop Drilling**. Would it be wise to learn about **Redux** to manage my state as well as use it to pass my data to other component *performance wise*.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

That actually depends on your use case. With hooks, context API you can achieve almost anything